# "Reduce motion" is not working when option "Displays have separate Spaces" is unchecked

Tags: spaces, mission-control, animation

has anyone answer to this please ?

The thing is, when I check "Displays have separate spaces" in Mission control settings, Reduce motion kicks in and it works....but when I want to have "one big space" across all monitors and I uncheck the option -  the animation is working again, but it shouldn't.

Comment: May I know why exactly I got negative votes ? No hard feeling, just curious.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) I flagged the post causing the downvote. Kindly consider reading through the support article [How to not be a spammer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). After an appropriate edit in place, the flag could be reversed.

Comment: I hope I got the article right, I made edits I think you meant