# Fix Slide animation for Command tab for mac

Tags: macos

Is there a way to completely remove the fade (or slide) animation when you switch (⌘+Tab) to a full-screen app that is on a different space?

Comment: Also duplicates:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/418393/119271, https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/384594/119271, https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/462713/119271,